# How to read the user login password by python script?

Tags: python

I have written the python script for switch off/on the monitor at a particular time using following command in my .py file.

```
passwd='Mypassword'    
subprocess.call('echo %s|sudo -S vbetool dpms on' % passwd, shell=True)
```

it works properly, but here i need to defined my password manually, but i need the system to automatically retrieve the password.

Is there any options available for the same, please let me know.

Comment: *From where* should the system retrieve the password?

Comment: Without further information, this question cannot be answered in a meaningful way.  Voting to close.

Answer (score 1):

Run the script as sudo. You can have a check to see if the user is sudo before trying to perform the command:

```
import os, sys

if not os.geteuid()==0:
    sys.exit("Please run as root")

os.system("vbetool dpms on")
```

Comment: i need to run my script as my user eg:administrator , i am not use the root.

Comment: If you are running sudo, you are running the command as root anyway. So run the python script with sudo. This **is** the way to "retrieve" the root password as another user.